# Unwanted scrollable horizontal space on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive, bulma

I am building this website http://104.236.64.172:8081 using Bulma CSS framework (probably irrelevant). The site is responsive and overall looks great on mobile devices except for one small problem that I am unable to fix.

If you open this link on your mobile phone you'll see that there is some unwanted horizontal space on the right side. Kind of like some spare `margin-right`. But the problem is I can't debug this on my desktop because it doesn't seem to appear on large screens with small widths. Can you help me debug this?

Comment: Can you provide script to go along with this?

Comment: As in, the whole HTML and CSS? That'll be impossible since it's, well, a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by hiding the overflow-x on the cont class.

For example:

```
.cont {
    max-width: 1110px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* THIS */
}
```

I tried adding this same implementation on cont's children classes, but it did not seem to resolve the issue the way that it did with it's parent. If someone has a better (or safer) resolution, feel free to use that instead of this as this may prove to create unwanted effects later on.

Also just as a tip, you should be able to use a web browser's (in my case Chrome) inspect feature in order to reproduce using a site on a mobile device. [Here's a quick walkthrough.](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/)

Comment: This does solve the problem but it seems like a hack.

Comment: Ya, I'm not super proud of it. It may cause unwanted effects later on (i.e. cutting off horizontal scrolling elements in the cont class). So if anyone can find a better solution, you may want to mark that as the solution.